# Fetch Email address with Facebook Profile

Tags: facebook

I am working on FaceBook Graph API.
1. I am able to connect with facebook connect, authenticate and redirect the user to dashboard of my website.
2. I now want to fetch the facebook profile details and update it locally on my website. so the profile is prepopulated as per the user facebook details.

Query :
1. I am able to fetch all other details but not the email address? I have tried passing the permission parameter and My code looks like : $result=json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$para.'&req_perms=email'));
2. The above URL is while I fetch the member Profile Details
3. Also please let me know to enable my account, to allow email address to be read by graph api.

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authorisations for permissions  and code samples on getting the user to authorise

http://blancer.com/tutorials/42760/how-to-authenticate-users-with-facebook-connect/